# Erro ao atualizar índice elasticsearch em angular

Tags: angular, elasticsearch

Basicamente tenho a seguinte função:

```
this.es.update({
            index: 'contentman',
            type: 'sites',
            id: "_id",
            body: {
              name: form.value.name,
              description: form.value.description,
              url: form.value.url,
              author: form.value.author,
              data_altered: new Date().toLocaleString()
            }
          }).then((hits) => {
          console.log(hits);
          alert('Site Editado, veja o log para mais informações');
          this.siteEdited(true);
```

Ao usar uma função que adiciona ao index tudo funciona corretamente:

```
  addToIndex(value): any {
    return this.client.index(value);
  }
```

Porém utilizando a função do ES de update:

```
update(value): any {
    return this.client.update(value);
  }
```

O `POST` retorna os seguintes erros no console:

```
RACE: 2019-05-09T11:39:24Z
  -> POST http://localhost:9200/contentman/sites/id/_update
  {
    "name": "nomeAtualizado...",
    "description": "",
    "data_altered": "09/05/2019 08:39:24"
  }
  <- 400
  {
    "error": {
      "root_cause": [
        {
          "type": "action_request_validation_exception",
          "reason": "Validation Failed: 1: script or doc is missing;"
        }
      ],
      "type": "action_request_validation_exception",
      "reason": "Validation Failed: 1: script or doc is missing;"
    },
    "status": 400
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui resolver este problema colocando dentro do `body` a tag `doc`:

```
this.es.update({
            index: 'contentman',
            type: 'sites',
            id: _id,
            body: {
              doc:{
                name: form.value.name,
                description: form.value.description,
                url: form.value.url,
                author: form.value.author,
                data_altered: new Date().toLocaleString()
              }
            }
          }).then((hits) => {
          console.log(hits);
          alert('Site Editado, veja o log para mais informações');
          this.siteEdited(true);
```